# nodejs: parsing chunks of json

Tags: json, node.js

I created a test server that sends chunks of stringified JSON.  When I connect to the server it sends invalid JSON and for the life of me I can't figure out why.  The output adds an extra double quotation mark.

Server code:

```
const net = require('net'),
server = net.createServer(function(connection) {
    console.log('subscriber connected.');

    // send first chunk immediately
    connection.write('{"type":"changed","file":"targ"');

    let timer = setTimeout(function() {
        connection.write('et.txt","timestamp":1358175758495}' + '\n');
        connection.end();
    }, 1000);

    connection.on('end', function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        console.log('subscriber disconnected');
    });
});

server.listen(5432, function() {
    console.log('test server listening for subs...')
});
```

ldj.js

```
'use strict';
const
    events = require('events'),
    util = require('util'),
    // client constructor
    LDJClient = function(stream) {
        events.EventEmitter.call(this);
        let self = this;
        let buffer = '';

        stream.on('data', function(data) {

            buffer += data;
            console.log(buffer)
            let boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n');
            while(boundary !== -1) {
                let input = buffer.substr(0, boundary);
                buffer = buffer.substr(boundary + 1);
                //self.emit('message', JSON.parse(input));
                boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n');
            }
        });
    };

util.inherits(LDJClient, events.EventEmitter);

// expose module methods
exports.LDJClient = LDJClient;
exports.connect = function(stream) {
    return new LDJClient(stream);
};
```

Output:

```
{"type":"changed","file":"targ"
{"type":"changed","file":"targ"et.txt","timestamp":1358175758495}
```

That extra " should not be in "target.txt" value. Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Can you post the server code? You'll need to make sure to buffer to the newline properly than parse. The fact that `file` isn't quoted at all in the output indicates something is going wacky on the server.

Comment: Extra double quote after `targ`:  `'{"type":"changed","file":"targ"'`?

Comment: ERR.  Thanks.  I forgot to re-run the node server after changes I made, making me think it didn't work. :/

Answer (score 0):

rathern than splitting string manualy try to get whole string and split it to chunks and then send it:

```
var data = '{"type":"changed","file":"target.txt","timestamp":1358175758495}';
var chunks = data.match(/.{1,10}/g); // 10 symbol chunks
for(var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
  var chunk = chunks[i];
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(connection) {
      connection.write(chunk+'\n');
      if(i + 1 == chunks.length) {
        connection.end();
      } 
    }
  }, i*1000);
}

connection.on('end', function() {
    console.log('subscriber disconnected');
});
```